# Relation between flow and exponential map

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, differential

In Proposition 1.7.12 in Hamilton's *Mathematical Gauge Theory* he states

> Let $G$ be a Lie group and $X$ a left-invariant vector field. Then its flow $\phi_t(p)$ through a point $p \in G$ is defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $$\phi:\mathbb{R} \times G \rightarrow G\\ (t,p) \mapsto \phi_t(p),$$ and given by $$\phi_t(p) = p \cdot \exp tX = R_{\exp tX}(p) = L_p (\exp tX).$$

In his notation $L_x$ and $R_x$ are left and right multiplication by $x$, and $D_e$ is the differential evaluated at $e$. His proof is

> Define $\phi_t(p)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ by the right-hand side. It is clear that $$\phi_0(p) = p \cdot \exp(0) = p.$$ Furthermore, $$\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t = s} \phi_t(p) = 
>  \frac{d}{d\tau} \Big|_{\tau = 0} L_p(\exp sX \cdot \exp \tau X)  \\ = D_e L_{p \exp sX}(X_e) \\ = X_{p \exp s X}  \\ = X_{\phi_s(p)},$$ since $X$ is left-invariant. This implies the claim by uniqueness of solutions of ordinary differential equations.

I am having some trouble understanding what he did in the first two lines/equalities. The first seems to be a change of variables. The second appears to be using the chain rule, but I am not seeing how he obtains $X_e$ or why he is evaluating the differential at $e$.

Comment: and $D_e$ is the what?

Comment: @Dr.TonyTonyChopper The differential evaluated at $e$. I just noticed the typo and have corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line is the change of variable $t = s + \tau$, using the fact that $$\exp tX = \exp ((s+\tau)X) = \exp(sX + \tau X) = \exp sX \cdot \exp \tau X.$$
The second line is the associativity of the product, and then the chain rule.
First, one has
$$
L_p (\exp sX \cdot \exp \tau X) = p \cdot (\exp sX \cdot \exp \tau X) = (p\cdot \exp sX)\cdot \exp \tau X = L_{p\cdot \exp sX}(\exp\tau X).
$$
Applying the chain rule, one has that
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d \tau} L_p (\exp sX \cdot \exp \tau X)
&= \frac{d}{d\tau} L_{p\cdot \exp sX}(\exp\tau X) \\
&= \left(D_{\exp \tau X}L_{p\cdot \exp sX}\right)\left(\frac{d}{d\tau}\exp\tau X\right),
\end{align}
and one concludes by evaluating at $\tau = 0$, since $\exp (0X) = \exp 0 = e$ and $(\frac{d}{d\tau}\exp \tau X)|_{\tau = 0} = X_e$.

Comment: Thank you! The only point that is still unclear to me is why $(\frac{d}{d\tau}\exp \tau X)|_{\tau = 0} = X_e$. Since $X$ belongs to the Lie algebra it is a left invariant vector field. When we compute the derivative we obtain $(\frac{d}{d\tau}\exp \tau X) = \exp \tau X X$, which when evaluated at $\tau = 0$ gives $X$. How do we go from $X$ to $X_e$?

Comment: @CBBAM At $\frac{d}{d\tau} \exp \tau X$ is the tangent vector of the integral curve of $X$ at time $\tau$ (i.e at the point $\exp \tau X$. At $\tau = 0$, it is the tangent vector to the integral curve of $X$ passing through $\exp 0 = e$, that is, $X_e$.

Comment: At that follows from the definition of $\phi$ being a flow for $X$?

Comment: @CBBAM yes exactly

Comment: Thank you for all your help!